# Test object implements interface from a dictionary

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have a dictionary of registered types.

```
Dictionary<Type, Type> knownTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Type>() {
   { typeof(IAccountsPlugin), typeof(DbTypeA) },
   { typeof(IShortcodePlugin), typeof(DbTypeB) }
};
```

I need to test if an object implements a specific interface as a key, and if so instantiate the counterpart value.

```
public Plugin FindDbPlugin(object pluginOnDisk)
{
    Type found;
    Type current = type.GetType();

    // the below doesn't work - need a routine that matches against a graph of implemented interfaces
    knownTypes.TryGetValue(current, out found); /
    if (found != null)
    {
        return (Plugin)Activator.CreateInstance(found);
    }
}
```

All types that will be created (in this case DbTypeA, DbTypeB and so forth) will only ever derive from type `Plugin`.

The object that is passed in may be inherited from one of the types we are trying to match (i.e. IAccountsPlugin) by several generations of inheritance. This is why I cannot do `pluginOnDisk.GetType()`.

Is there a way to test if an object implements a type, and then create the new instance of that type, with a dictionary lookup rather than brute forcing and testing typeof in a long loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this method to be generic, and specify the type of the object you are looking for:

```
public Plugin FindDbPlugin<TKey>(TKey pluginOnDisk)
{
    Type found;
    if (knownTypes.TryGetValue(typeof(TKey), out found) && found != null)
    {
        Plugin value = Activator.CreateInstance(found) as Plugin;
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Type is not a Plugin.");
        }

        return value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Example:**

```
IAccountsPlugin plugin = ...
Plugin locatedPlugin = FindDbPlugin(plugin);
```

Comment: also if(!(found is Plugin)){ throw new InvalidOperationException("does not implement Plugin"); }

Comment: You have no return statement when `TKey` is not in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
public Plugin FindDbPlugin(object pluginOnDisk) {        
    Type found = pluginOnDisk.GetType().GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(t => knownTypes.ContainsKey(t));
    if (found != null) {
        return (Plugin) Activator.CreateInstance(knownTypes[found]);
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Type is not a Plugin.");
}
```